# How to write JUnit test cases for a SpringBoot Application which does not have @SpringBootApplication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I have 2 SpringBoot separate applications created Core Project and Rest Project.

1. Core Project :- Has the services for the CRUD operations called from
   from Rest Project.
2. Rest Project :- Which has the @SpringBootApplication which calls the
   Core Project services from the controller.

**Note:** Core project is added as a dependency to Rest Project.

### I want to write testcases for the core project .

**While creating the JUNit tests I am getting this error in JUnit:**

> - org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper
>   -> Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class core.repository.SampleRepositoryTests, using
>   SpringBootContextLoader
> - DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader -> Did
>   not detect default resource location for test class
>   core.repository.SampleRepositoryTests: class path resource
>   core/repository/SampleRepositoryTests-context.xml does not exist
> - DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader -> Did
>   not detect default resource location for test class
>   core.repository.SampleRepositoryTests: class path resource
>   core/repository/SampleRepositoryTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
> - INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader -> Could not detect default resource locations for test class core.repository.SampleRepositoryTests]: no resource found for suffixes
>   {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
> - INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils
>   -> Could not detect default configuration classes for test class core.repository.SampleRepositoryTests: ProjectRepositoryTests does not
>   declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated
>   with @Configuration.
> - DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils -> Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class
>   core.repository.SampleRepositoryTests

**The stack trace is:**

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOrFindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:236)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:152)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:393)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:262)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

**For reference :-** I found a similar scenario https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-unable-to-find-springbootconfiguration-with-datajpatest#missing-springbootconfiguration , but same error is coming when configuring similarly.

Comment: Your core project isn't a spring boot application just a regular java project, which happens to have some spring dependencies. With that being said you have to use the plain Spring test support and **not** the Spring Boot test support.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you annotated your junit test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

That initializes the Spring context but does not configure and add any beans to it. So if you will try to `@Authowire` or use any other Spring functionality, it will fail.

You have two options here:

1. Configure and add bean that you are testing (for example, `MyService`) by adding  `@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyService.class)` or `@SpringBootTest(classes=MyService.class)` or by providing test configuration as described here, for example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing
2. Remove `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation and create instance of the class you will be testing manually, via `new`. But this is not preferable options, it will not autocreate mocks etc...

Comment: What is the MyService class that you have represented in the 1st option. It will be great if you could give an example for testing our module that doesn't contain any @SpringBootConfiguration.

Comment: That is class that you want to unit test, you sain you have crud services in core project so MyService can be one of those. I can give an example but later

Comment: The error indicates that he tries to use `@SpringBootTest` (or another slice like `@DataJpaTest`) which fails with the said error because his project simply isn't a spring boot project, but a regular java project with some spring dependencies.